# LVM over 1x SSD + 1x HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, lvm, sshd

I am just wondering if somebody thought about this: in a system constellation with a SSD and a HDD would setting up a LVM that would include both generate something similar to a SSHD? Would the system know to take advantage of the speed of the SSD for the main parts and for the ones that are often used?

My idea would be to set up the both SSD and HDD as PVs (Physical Volume), to group them together in a LV (Logical Volume) where to install the system mounted as /

I thought about this for a machine that will store some VMs (eventually one with a passthrough GPU that would need the speed of the SSD)  and I would not split the space in order to let the VMs to dynamically use it and not to spend efforts to manage which VM is saved where on the disk...

Let's assume that the SSD is 240 - 500 GB and the HDD 1-2 TB...

Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I am running on my machine, I've never used an sshd so I can't speak to that, but the performance is well enough for my needs (seems to usually slightly faster than just my HDD) however see tht following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53217/lvm-with-ssd-and-sata-hard-disks

Comment: I'm also fairly certain You can specify one or more physical volumes to restrict where LVM allocates the data. if you are really worried about speed of certain things